# How to Change scroll position using jquery smooth scoll

Tags: jquery, scroll

Hi all Here is my Question

I am working with 'jquery smooth scroll' 
this scroll is properly coming but I want this to come little bit bottom around 50px from the top something like this

```
$('.main_nav li a').click(function(event) {
    $('.main_nav li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = this;
        $.smoothScroll({
            scrollTarget: link.hash **-50px**
       });
});
```

is that possible in jquery smooth scroll? 
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want is the offset setting:

```
     ...
     $.smoothScroll({
         scrollTarget: link.hash,
         offset: -50
     });
     ...
```

You might also want to use `scrollElement: null` to ensure you scroll the whole document.

From: https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll#fnsmoothscroll

Comment: Thank you so much DaveMongoose :)